# Country names list

Tags: android

To find country name of the device current geo location in Android. The accurate way is using the **longtude** and **latitude** to get `android.location.Address` object which contains `getCountryName()` method.

**My Question:** Where can I find the full list of country names that Android uses? in other words, the list of countries that `getCountryName()` get result from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's in `Locale` class.

Call `getAvailableLocales()` then iterate the array & getDisplayCountry()

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();

            countries.add(country);

    }
 Collections.sort(countries);
```

---

**Output**

```
Albania
Algeria
Argentina
Australia
..
Venezuela
Vietnam
Yemen
```

Comment: How can you be sure that this is the same list?